# Loading data for Android when switching views in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Came over a very strange problem with Eclipse.

I'm using Android platforms 4.0 to 4.4. And when i'm for example switching the tabs or opening a new tab in the top that shows the current opened layouts/views Eclipse starts to load all platforms again (Loading data For Android 4.x), from 4.0 to 4.4, and then rebuilds the workspace.

This makes Eclipse totally unusable as it's crashes when switching views. I hadn't this problem a couple of days ago, it started acting up after I received a update from Eclipse for two/three days ago.

Anyone knows what the problem is? Or can help me solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I experienced the same issue, and the solution was to download the SDK again from Android: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html**

I tried to revert the ADT from 22.6.0, which was the one giving this errors, to 22.3.0, but couldn't do it manually. So the solution was to download the SDK again from Android, because ironically, the online version at the time of this answer is still the old version of ADT (22.3.0), which works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Cannot up-vote cause to low rep, but thank you really!